# How do I organise "orderDate" into First date of each week

Tags: sql, date

MSSQL --

I'm looking to change my data from

```
OrderDate      Amt
2012-03-05     1
2012-03-06     6
2012-03-06     7
2012-03-07     8
2012-03-08     1
2012-03-08     1
```

I would like it to list what the start of the week date was, e.g. 2012-01-01 (assume this is sunday) and group all amounts for the week into that date..

How is this possible in SQL?

Thanks
James.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: MSSQL, will edit into my post sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  Select DateAdd(D,1-DatePart(Dw,OrderDate),OrderDate) OrderStartOfWeekDate,
         Sum(Amt) TotalAmt
    From Tbl
Group by DateAdd(D,1-DatePart(Dw,OrderDate),OrderDate);
```

Comment: You beat me by a couple of minutes, here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d82c0/5) with pretty much the same approach.

Comment: Thats a cool site actually! seems very limited in it's uses, but perfect for displaying working code!